# Is there a specific schema.org type that fits well for structured data on a webbook with multiple chapters?

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data

I wrote, built, and published a webbook on my personal website. To disambiguate, the word "webbook" refers to a book whose content is directly readable on a website in HTML format, not an epub to download or a PDF.

This webbook is split across multiple webpages. Each webpage is a chapter.

I am currently working on the meta-aspects required by the medium: performance, SEO, usability, accessibility, etc. Which leads me to the structured data question.

So my question is: What can I declare as structured data for a webbook?

I have found schema.org's "CreativeWork", which is kind of matching a webbook yet a little vague, and its subtype "Chapter". I have also found "WebContent", but it's vague as well.

"Book" seems limited to physical books. And it looks like it is not supported by any major company (or you must be big enough to appear on Google's apps). "Article" seemed to fit at first, but the way Google presents the data makes it—in my opinion—unfit for the task (chapters appearing as articles in a news feed). As a side note, I also checked Bing's Webmaster Tools help about its supported types, but even fewer options are listed compared to Google.

Maybe I should just give up on trying to properly declare my content because I would get no benefit from that structured data?

> If you want to see the webbook I'm talking about, you can access it here (it's in French but the content is not what matters for my issue): https://nemulumen.lightnovel.online/tnbs1/

Comment: This question is about SEO and not programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Hover over the SEO tag and read that popup.

Comment: OK, I read it. I tried to delete that question as indicated by the tag but I cannot due to already posted answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Book`](https://schema.org/Book) is the right type here.

It’s not limited to physical/paper-based works, as its definition just says "A book", without mentioning the format. There’s also the [`bookFormat`](https://schema.org/bookFormat) property, for which values like [`EBook`](https://schema.org/EBook) and [`AudiobookFormat`](https://schema.org/AudiobookFormat) are defined, which wouldn’t make sense if the `Book` type were only intended for paper-based books.

To convey that the `Book` is available as HTML, you can use the [`encoding`](https://schema.org/encoding) property (where the `Book` would represent the work, and the [`MediaObject`](https://schema.org/MediaObject) would represent the HTML encoding of this work), or the [`encodingFormat`](https://schema.org/encodingFormat) property.

To connect the `Book` with each [`Chapter`](https://schema.org/Chapter), you can use the [`hasPart`](https://schema.org/hasPart)/[`isPartOf`](https://schema.org/isPartOf) property.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that we could add the bookFormat property. I've checked on Wikipedia the definition of what is an ebook, and it looks like ebooks are not limited to the epub, pdf and such; HTML format books may be thought as well as ebooks (even txt files haha). The only thing I have to make clear is about the "edition" (with the help of this encoding property you mentioned) of the ebook, because I will later offer to download an epub version of the same content (ebook as HTML + ebook as epub).